# How to erase item inside of item in nlohmann::json file C++

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I want to know how I can delete an item within an item in the [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) C++ library.

Json example file:

```json
{
    "Users":{
        "User1":{
            "Name":"BOB",
            "DeleteMe":"IWantToBeDeleted!"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to delete is "DeleteMe":"IWantToBeDeleted!" that is inside of "Users" and "User1"
I have looked at the documentation for [basic_json::erase](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/erase/) but I can only see how to delete an item in the root of the json file, for example "Users" in my example file.

Any help would be appreciated =D

Comment: I think you can probably do what you need with a combination of [`json_pointer`](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/doxygen/classnlohmann_1_1json__pointer_a7f32d7c62841f0c4a6784cf741a6e4f8.html) and `erase`. Use the pointer to get *a reference* to the `User1` node, and `erase` to remove the `DeleteMe` node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`basic_json::erase`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/erase/) only erases from the currently referenced `json` node -- so if your `json` object is the outer object, that would be why you can only erase top-level entries. What you want is a way to get the internal node `User1` and call `erase` on the `DeleteMe` key from there.

You should be able to easily get a reference to `User1` using [`json_pointer`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/json_pointer/) -- which is basically a string-path of the nodes required to traverse to get the node you want. Once you have the node, it should be as simple as calling `erase`.

Something like this:

```cpp
auto json = nlohmann::json{/* some json object */};
auto path = nlohmann::json_pointer<nlohmann::json>{"/Users/User1"};


// Get a reference to the 'user1' json object at the specified path
auto& user1 = json[path];

// Erase from the 'user1' node by key name
user1.erase("DeleteMe");
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Gn3e9fv8K)</kbd>

Comment: This can be slightly improved by using two neat functions provided by _json_pointer_ itself, `parent_pointer()` and `back()`, so there's no need to split key path "_manually_" `auto ptr = nlohmann::json::json_pointer( "/Users/User1/DeleteMe" ); json.at( ptr.parent_pointer() ).erase( ptr.back() );` https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/avxT5q9YP